# Adding user input strings to an ArrayList and printing these in a TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

so I'm just getting started in Java/Android Development and currently working on an assignment which I've gotten to work the way I want it to except for one part. So in this app you are supposed to be able to add "sandwiches" to an order, and then have your order presented below. I have the user adding sandwiches through a ListView with clickable options, as that's the idea, but then when presenting the order I want to store and present all the clicks, i.e. all the mackor that "have been ordered" in the TextView below the ListView, however I only manage to store and present one selection at a time, and when another one is clicked, the previous one is replaced. I've been trying to read up on this and I'm thinking a for or do-while loop should probably be used for this? However I did try a couple different versions of that without getting it to work, so here I am.

So tl;dr everything is working the way I want it to except for the selections just "replacing" eachother instead of adding up - how do I add a String/object to the ArrayList everytime a user selects an option in the ListView instead of having it just switching these? I was advised to use ArrayList to store these selections, but right now it's not of much use as it's just holding one at a time lol. I'm sure there are a lot of other things not done ideally in this program as well but yeah. Any advice on how to get this to work properly would be much appreciated! I figured my XML shoulnd't be necessary to include as that's not the issue but I gladly will if needed.

Comment: what you are doing on click of a button you are creating a new array so move your array assign out of the scope of click listener first  then try

Comment: It's helped you iam glad to know about that